# Display single column data in multiple columns with different condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a columns of IDs with large volume of data and I want to retrieve Unique, duplicates etc in a single query that can display data in below format. Please suggest a query.

```
ID_Duplicates: a b c
ID_null      : w, x, y, z
```

Answer (score 0):

To search duplicate entries use:

```
Distinct keyword
```

Do some programming like:

```
if(duplicate){

}
else{

}
```